# shared_ptr of abstract base class as member

Tags: c++, std, shared-ptr

I have an abstract base class, let's call it Message, and a derived class called StatusMessage.

A wrapper class must hold a shared_ptr to any of the derived message classes. The message gets assigned on construction.

```
StatusMessage status_message{"status"};
WrapperClass wrapper{"user", status_message};
```

Now my question is: how can I make the shared_ptr inside the WrapperClass point to the StatusMessage object? Obviously make_shared won't work, because that would try to construct an object of the abstract Message class.

```
message_ptr = std::make_shared<Message>(status_message);
```

Using references instead of std_pointer is not an option in my opinion because my Message objects get constructed in different classes and will be destroyed before the destruction of the Wrapper. This is why I chose shared_ptr instead.

Thanks in advance! Feel free to ask for more information if needed.

A general outline of the structure:

```
class Message {
public:
  virtual ~OcppMessage() {}
};

class StatusMessage : public Message {
public:
  void doSomething();
};

class Wrapper {
public:
  Wrapper();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Message> message_;
};
```

**UPDATE 1**

So what I'm trying out now is creating the derived message objects as shared pointers and then assigning them to the member variable in the constructor. I wrote a small test program to showcase the idea and this seems to work.

```
  std::shared_ptr<Message> base_ptr_;

  auto status_message = std::make_shared<StatusMessage>("status");

  base_ptr_ = status_message;

  std::shared_ptr<StatusMessage> derived_ptr =
      std::dynamic_pointer_cast<StatusMessage>(base_ptr_);

  REQUIRE(derived_ptr->status == "status");
```

Comment: `Obviously make_shared won't work, because that would try to construct an object of the abstract Message class.` If you tell it to create a `Message`, sure. Tell it to make a `StatusMessage` then.

Comment: The problem is that I want to hold different kinds of messages. Not only a StatusMessage but a TimeMessage, ErrorMessage - whatever. When the constructor gets called I don't know what kind of message has been passed.

Comment: You _do_ know what message you want when you create it. So call `std::make_shared` with the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you're suggesting that I overload the constructor for every possible message there is?

Comment: `shared_ptr` completely supports polymorphism and will absolutely work even if it's type is an abstract `class`. You just have to assign to it an instance of a `shared_ptr` of the actual derived type.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So my new idea would be to create the derived object as a shared_ptr before passing it to the constructor. `auto status_message = make_shared<StatusMessage>("status");` And then assign it to my member variable in the constructor.